# Does time spent setting up work environment count towards hours worked?

Tags: contractors, invoices

I recently started a job as a contractor. My boss wants a written daily report detailing what I will do today and what I did yesterday and how much time was spent on each item. The level of detail he wants is quite high. A lot of time is spent setting things up and trouble shooting random issues. For example, the video playback on videos I had to watch for work kept freezing. Yesterday I spent 30 minutes updating codecs and getting a new media player. Do these 30 minutes count towards "work" and should I include this in my daily report and invoice? What about the time spent installing and configuring new applications or troubleshooting old ones (like when Skype randomly stops working)? Another specific I'm wondering about, I'm required to take internal training to learn a system, does the time I take to organize notes count towards work?

Comment: We did not sign your contract nor any of the policies you agreed to, so you will have to check those and/or simply ask your boss/client.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul it's pretty standard "something that is done per the specifications of client"

Comment: If it's so standard then why are you asking us, and not just adopt the standard way to do it? Again, we don't know, we cannot know, why won't you simply ask your boss exactly what you've asked us?

Comment: Can you ask them?

Comment: I am more concerned if it's fair or not. @guest

Comment: The issue is, the term "contractor" is quite overloaded, and what is generally acceptable or common can vary significantly. If your contract is quite vague, you should find a peer that works in the same industry and location, and try to determine what is acceptable from them.

Comment: And you may be better off working for a contracting company, at least until you get a feel for what is acceptable and normal.

Comment: If you need to do those things for work, then it's fair imo that you get compensated.

Comment: I suggest you stop calling your client “my boss”.

Answer (score 5):

maybe

That totally depends on your contract.

The way I see it, if I have to do it because of work, it is work. You want me to use skype? those skype troubles are billed. You have a shitty VPN client with stupid configuration? Those hours are billed. I spend 20 hours researching for nothing because the request was badly phrased? those hours are billed.

Of course, there is a line. A customer can assume that you have a PC with a working OS on it...

It is not standard to get super detailed on invoices. Depending on customer, how fine grained it is was different.
From "development work" everyday in the project, and just how many hours that day, to which rough topics I worked that day.
The invoice to your level of detail is super rare, and I would push back against it.

I would advise against asking your boss after the fact, that just opens up discussions. And it makes you exploitable because you show weakness. The greedy boss will try to define as much work as possible as not billable, while still expecting you to do it. Your boss might be different, just be wary of this.

If you are unsure, ask BEFORE you do it. And if he says no, dont do it. Will I be able to bill X? No -> Dont do it.

Comment: Agree. Don't ask the boss. That's pretty obvious. If you're a contractor, you're acting like a business. Businesses don't ask other businesses if they should charge for things. If you're running a store, you don't ask a customer if they would like to pay for something or just get it for free.

Comment: It's a bit of a balancing act. If the contract allows either party to walk away on a whim, billing the client for very minor things, may be a quick way to lose the job.

Comment: Be prepared that you annoy other people really fast if whenever you need to do things like installing Skype, other things, you need to find a  person responsible for finances and ask them.

Comment: I have another specific example. I'm doing training to learn how to use an internal system. If I take time to make a good copy of my notes does this count towards work or not because my boss didn't specifically say to take notes?

Comment: @cooltrix15 You are thinking like an internal person. Maybe you are a fake contractor, and you really are internal. Then you should check your local laws what they say about this. maybe you just need some time to mentally adjust. But as contractor, you provide a service. And you decide how you do it (and typically, when to do it). So if you decide taking notes is better in the long run for providing the best service, then it's part of your billed hours.

Comment: also, maybe instead of boss, start calling him something like customer or client.  Maybe call him the customers Project Lead, or Project Lead for short. But when you trully are contractor, that person pays your bills, but you are your boss.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie right, it becomes a business decision rather than an ethical or workplace policy one. A restaurant could start charging customers 5 cents for each napkin, but I doubt I'd want to eat there.

Comment: I know a good asian restaurant, and most people order the food for takeawy. At one point I started giving special order, mostly combinations that are not on the card like this. In the beginning they always told me what this or that special wish costs. I always answered: "That's ok, Ill pay it". Now they just cook whatever I ask for and I pay the price at the end. Other people observed this and started ordering specials. They of course get informed about the cost, and sometimes they say no and order by the card instead. If you want plastic cutlery to take away, thats for free though!

Answer (score -3):

Any time where you cannot do what you like counts as work. Say you are playing football with your kids from 8am to 8:40am (not work) and 8:40 you start setting up Skype for an important call at 9am. Since you had to stop playing football with the kids, the setup time from 8:40 to 9:00 is work.

Comment: That's a bit oversimplified. If OP has to walk/drive home, take a shower and change into business clothing, that's unlikely to count.

Comment: That's a little bit oversimplified. For example, a taxi driver in my country does not have the right to expect more money from me if he waited 5 minutes until I come, even though he cannot spend the time with kids.

Comment: This might be correct for employees, but certainly not for contractors. It's also oversimplified even for employees. If I get stuck in traffic on my way to work, that's on me, whether I'm employed or contractor. If I need to buy a new car because the old one broke down, still on me. Buying a faster machine for work as a contractor? On me.